# Accessing properties of a child view created within {{#each}} iterator

Tags: ember.js

**Edit:** Problem was with my own local settings and the way I was including the views in my application. Once I fixed those issues, the problem was resolves. The code here is actually correct. The answer Chrixian provided also work.

I am stuck on something that seems rather simple. I want to access some computed properties of my view constructed inside an each loop in handlebars.

```
<div class='build-buttons-wrapper'>
  <button class="list-builds-button" {{action "toggleBuildsList" target="view"}} ></button>
  <button class="build-button" {{action "buildApp" on="click" target="view"}} >Build</button>
</div>
<div class='builds-list'>
  <h2 class="build-title">Latest builds</h2>
  <ul class="builds-list">
  {{#each content}}
    {{#view Jimux.BuildView buildBinding="this"}}
      <span class="build-date">{{createdAt}}</span>
      <a {{bindAttr href="srcArchive"}} class="download-button source">Source</a>

      {{! *here are different ways I have tried to access "finished" property* }}
      {{log build.view.finished}}
      {{log view.finished}}
      {{log finished}}
      {{log this.finished}}
      {{log build.finished}}

      {{#if build.finished}}
        <div class="build-progressbar"></div>
      {{else}}
        <div class="build-progressbar"><div class="build-percent" style="width:{{unbound percent}}%"></div></div>
      {{/if}}
    {{/view}}
  {{/each}}
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the `BuildsView` which is using this template:

```
  Jimux.BuildsView = Em.View.extend({
  templateName: 'builds'
  listVisible: false
  classNames: ['builds-view']
  buildApp: (view, event, ctx) ->
    @get('controller').newBuild()
  ,
  hideList: ->
    @set 'listVisible', false
    this.$(".builds-list").hide("slide", {direction: "up"}, 300)
  ,
  showList: ->
    @set 'listVisible', true
    this.$(".builds-list").show("slide", {direction: "up"}, 300)
  ,
  toggleBuildsList: (view, event, ctx) ->
    if @get 'listVisible' then @hideList() else @showList()
  ,
  didInsertElement: ->
    @hideList() if not @get 'listVisible'

})
```

And here is the `BuildView` which is created inside the `{{#each}}` iterator in the template above.

```
Jimux.BuildView = Ember.View.extend(
  tagName: 'div',
  classNames: ['build-item'],
  #testBinding: true,
  sample: true,
  finished: ( ->
    return true
    #return (@get 'percent') == 100
  ).property('percent')
)
```

Everything above works as expected. For example I can access percent property of each child view using {{percent}}. But if I define my own properties inside the `Jimux.BuildView` as show above, I cant seem to find a way to access them within the handlebars `{{#each}}` iterator. You can see the different ways I have tried inside the handlebars code with `{{log}}` statements, all those print `undefined` in the console. What am I missing here?

Comment: what version of handlebars/emberjs are you running?

Comment: @jonnii `Handlebars.VERSION = "1.0.rc.1";` do you think that has something to do with this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming the `percent` property you are referring to is a property of each "content" object you are looping over-- if that's the case making finished look like this:

```
finished: (->
    return @get('context.percent') is 100
).property('context.percent')
```

You should be able to simply use `{{finished}}` within the `{{#view Jimux.BuildView}} .. {{/view}}` block

Comment: +1 for reading my long post and thanks for your response! Where should I put this finished computed property? In the BlocksView which has the template or the BlockView which is instantiated inside the template, or somewhere else?

Comment: ok, hard to admit, but it was a silly mistake on my part. My original code is correct. Your code also works as expected. Thanks for taking the time to answer and sorry for false alarm!